# Is there a way to bring up the regular P4V submit window from a custom tool script?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I need to run a very brief batch script before submitting the selected changelist - instead of then submitting the changelist through *p4 submit*, I'd like to just bring up the regular submit window that is used when submitting via P4V. Is there any way to do this from the custom tool batch script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In later versions of the p4v client Perforce shipped a command line utility to do exactly what you're looking for,  p4vc

I think it was added in 2012.1 or thereabouts (not at work so can't check)

Off the top of my head the command line would be p4vc submit -c changelist   to bring up the p4v submit dialog.